# Use one single table for users' passwords

Tags: database

I'm writing a small remote password manager. A client can register itself and stores its passwords (it is for university purposes).
In practice, I have a table `Client_ID | hash(Password)` that stores the user's hashed password. From this password, I use a `KDF` to create a `32B AES PASSWORD` that I will use to encrypt the user's passwords.

At first, I created a table `user_table = site | AES(password_site) | AES_IV` for every new user. But, then I thought that I could use only one single table for all the users like this `users_table = client_ID | site | AES(password_site) | AES_IV`, with `client_ID` and `site` as the primary key.

What is the best method? And if a method is not secure or not convenient, why?

Comment: This is more a question about proper table organization and not so much security.

Really what you're asking is how you should allocate your foreign keys on your tables so that you can realistically manage a users password(s).

This should be as easy as a user table with identifier(s)[email, username] | password(and however you choose to protect it) | id(your easy to use reference that never changes), and a sites table with user(the id field from the users table as a foreign key) | site | password(two way encryption based on some user secret/other logic)

Comment: after that you'll probably want an index to keep things fast on user in the passwords table

Comment: thank you for the reply. So It is better to use only one table for all the users.

Comment: Depending. You need a table for reference, then after that you can move to model. So yes you should have a single table per entity(if no other entity is required but username, then yes user)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused. I have a table for `client_ID | hash(psw)`. With this, I check the login. My question is how to organize the tables where I save the passwords of a user. I have two ideas: 1. one table for each user (so if I have 100 users, than 100 tables) like `site | password` (for simplicity)  or 2. one single table for all the users (100 users, 1 table) like `user_ID | site | password` (for simplicity) ? Obviously  in the second case, I have to link the user_IDs of the 2 tables

Comment: ah. Either of those two models will work. The problem then becomes which is faster and more maitnainable

Comment: For security reason are these models the same? This project is for cybersecurity course, so the first thing is security, 'then' the performances

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79107/discussion-between-robert-mennell-and-linofex).